# How to print out spock metadata(the conent of given|when|then) when specs running?

Tags: printing, metadata, spock

Is it possible or not?If yes,it will be a big help for debugging.

Update:
For metadata,I mean the content of after given|when|then statement,such as:

```
def "test case"...
given:"some preconditions"
when:"do something"
then:"some result"
...
```

I want that blow content got printed:

```
"test case" begins
"some preconditions"
"do something"
"some result"
```

Comment: Thanks for this "comprehensive" question. Define "meta data", please. Also provide sample code. Are you maybe talking about text labels such as `given: "empty input form on registration page"`?

Comment: @kriegaex,yes,and I updated questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not possible because even if you write a Spock extension, the deepest you can hook into at the moment is feature method execution. I.e. what you could do is print all block labels before or after a method is executed, but not interspersed with your own log output during method execution. There is no hook or interception point for intra-method block execution at the moment.

See also these feature requests (still unanswered, unfortunately):

- https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/538
- https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/645

What is also possible around logging block labels is to write HTML test reports as a test documentation. But this is a reporting thing and not something you can use during a running test.

---

**Update:** Meanwhile a little workaround. Put this in your global Spock config script (usually `src/test/resources/SpockConfig.groovy`:

```java
import spock.lang.Specification

class LabelPrinter {
  def _(def message) {
    println message
    true
  }
}

Specification.mixin LabelPrinter
```

Then use it from Spock or Geb tests like this (please note the underscores after the labels):

```java
package de.scrum_master.testing

import spock.lang.Specification

class MySpockTest extends Specification {
  def "interaction"() {
    given:_ "My given comment"
    def foo = 11
    def bar = foo + 4
    println "blah"

    expect:_ "My expect comment"
    interaction {
      foo = 2
      bar = 5
      true
    }
    println "foo"
    foo * bar == 10
    foo + bar == 7

    and:_ "My and comment"
    true
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
My given comment
blah
My expect comment
foo
My and comment
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with a nice little workaround.

Comment: Apologies if I'm raising the dead a little here. Is it possible to set that hook to just print out all of the given, when, thens etc?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Please elaborate.

Comment: So instead of declaring a function _ and mixing it in, having something that automatically prints out `given`, `when` and `then` clauses without needing the `_` ?

Comment: That question has already been answered. Please re-read my answer and also follow the links to the open Spock tickets.

Comment: It seems that this PR https://github.com/spockframework/spock/pull/1575 will enable creation of extension that will do this by default (?). This solution works but is annoying because default intellij formatter goes crazy when it sees label with underscore after and some text and it breaks formatting :(

Comment: It does not "go crazy", but it correctly identifies `_ "something"` as a Groovy method call and puts the method call statement on its own line. Just replace it by `println "something"` or `println("something")`, and the exact same thing occurs. My workaround does not replace #1575, but it _works around_ it. Feel free to open an issue for IDEA to get an option to suppress wrapping of statements after labels in the formatter.

Comment: FYI, I have just created [IDEA-347164](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-347164) for the formatter issue.