# Execute action every 'when' step Spock

Tags: java, testing, groovy, spock

I want to do action takeScreen() every 'when' step (Spock). How can I do that without calling this function every 'when' step.

```
 def "doSomeAction"() {
    when:
    doSmth()
    takeScreen()
    then:
    at SomePage
    when:
    doAction()
    takeScreen()
    then:
    at SomePage
}

def takeScreen(){
    //code there
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. What's the big deal?

BTW, assuming you are using Geb + Spock to test some kind of web application and just in case `takeScreen()` is meant to take screenshots, why don't you just derive your Geb test from `GebReportingSpec` and use `report "After login"` or so?

**Update:** A workaround would be adding a little helper method to your class or just to the global Spock configuration and call it after `when:` or `then:`. See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42169412/1082681) for details on how to do that. Instead of (or in addition to) printing labels you could do whatever `takeScreen()` is supposed to do or just call it from there. If you want it at the beginning of `when:`, make sure the method is called like `when:_ "bla"`, if you want it at the end like in your example, you would call it in the subsequent `then:` like `then:_ "bla"`. But I do not think that you should do it that way, in your case it is just information hiding. A test should show exactly what it does. In my projects developers had problems inside helper methods themselves many times, especially in Geb around taking screenshots for failing tests for reasons off-topic and too complex to explain here.